# Not crossing one's legs in Bhishma's advice: Meaning and scriptural explanations?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma, brahmacharya

Consider the following words by Bhishma to Yudhistrira

> One should always observe the vow of Brahmacharya, and **should never cross one's legs**. One should observe the vow of Brahmacharya on the day of the new moon, as also on that of the full moon, as also on the eighth lunar day of both fortnights.
>
> [[Section 104, Anusasanika Parva, The Mahabharata
> ]](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b069.htm)

What is meant by 'crossing one's legs' here? Do any scripture mention this rule in more detail? Do they describe the rationale behind this rule in more detail?

Comment: hard to glean esoteric meanings without original sanskrit text and a scholar.

Comment: Imo, it refers to crossing ur legs while you are sitting on something like chair. You know that pose people sit with putting one leg on other while sitting in chair. I don't think this here refers to sitting cross legged on earth like when we sit in padmasan or siddhasan.

Comment: I have written an answer, you may check it, if you wish https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58398/24460 @ram

Comment: You may check the answer too, if you are interested @Rudra

Answer (score 4):

The question of the OP is regarding the following phrase -

> pādaṁ pādena nākramet / (Anuśāsana Parva 104.29)

This is a pretty direct phrase, which means that one shouldn't press a pāda on another pāda. 
However, this niṣedha doesn't apply to sitting in sukhāsana, padmāsana, etc., because these āsanas are such that a leg is kept & pressed over another leg. As @Rudra pointed in his comment on the OP's post, this niṣedha would primarily apply in the case of standing or sitting on chair/stool/table, in a normative manner (not sukhāsana, etc.).

Nīlakaṇṭha doesn't comment upon this śloka, in his [ṭīkā Bhāratabhāvadīpa](https://archive.org/details/mahabharata_nk/page/n3821/mode/2up?view=theater). 
Śabdakalpadruma, in its [entry on 'pādaḥ'](https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/SKDScan/2020/web/webtc/servepdf.php?dict=skd&page=Page3-110-a+%2052), cites 'Karmalocana', which mentions this niṣedha -

> pādena nākramet pādamucchiṣṭaṁ naiva laṅghayet na saṁhatābhyāṁ pāṇibhyāṁ kaṇḍūyedātmanaḥ śiraḥ //

[Notices of Sanskrit Manuscripts (Vol. 2, pg. 11, entry 542)](https://archive.org/details/NoticesOfSanskritManuscriptsVol.IIRajendralalaMitra/page/n19/mode/2up?view=theater) says regarding Karmalocana -

> A work of some repute on modern religious observances, the mode of performing them, and the fruits thereof. The MS. is a mere fragment

The same niṣedha (pādaṁ pādena nākramet) occurs in some other śāstras too-

> na huṁ kuryācchivaṁ pūjyaṁ pādaṁ pādena nā''kramet / 
> pratyakṣaṁ vā parokṣaṁ vā kasyacinnāpriyaṁ vadet // 
> ~ Agni Purāṇa ([155.28](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaChowkhambaSurbharati/page/n347/mode/2up?view=theater))

> na kṣiptapādajaṅghaśca prājñastiṣṭhetkadācana / 
> na cāpi vikṣipetpādau pādaṁ pādena nākramet // 
> ~ Mārkaṇḍeya Purāṇa ([31.46](https://archive.org/details/DetC_markandeya-puran-pt.-kanhaiyya-lal-ji-mishra/page/n251/mode/2up?view=theater))

> pādena nākrametpādaṁ na pūjyābhimukhaṁ nayet / 
> noccāsanaṁ guroragre bhajetāvinayānvitaḥ // 
> ~ Viṣṇu Purāṇa ([3.12.25](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n217/mode/2up?view=theater))

None of these quoted references provide any elucidation/elaboration on the niṣedha (pādaṁ pādena nākramet). Viṣṇu Purāṇa has two known Saṁskṛta commentaries viz. Śrīdharasvāmi's [Ātmaprakāśa](https://archive.org/details/vp_vol1/page/n507/mode/2up?view=theater) and Eṅgaḷāḻvān's [Viṣṇucittīya](https://archive.org/details/Vishnu_Purana_with_Vishnuchittiyam_-_PB_Annangaracharya_1972/page/n239/mode/2up?view=theater), and both don't bother explaining the said niṣedha (which is too direct). In the three Purāṇas referenced, the niṣedha (pādaṁ pādena nākramet) is mentioned in the adhyāya expounding on sadācāras i.e. the ācāra which is to be followed (or that's upheld by śiṣtas), such as 'not uttering huṁ to a pūjya person.' In this case, it should be clear that 'pādaṁ pādena nākramet' is a direct statement regarding ācāra, which is to be taken literally. And sādācāra of śiṣṭas/sādhus are not required to have a reason. They(sadācāra) are accepted as a source of dharma, provided they don't outrightly conflict with śāstras.

> śruti (Veda), smr̥tis, sadācāra of śiṣṭas/sādhus, and ātmasantuṣṭi/ātmapriya are the fourfold sources of knowing dharma (Manusmr̥ti 2.6, 2.12)